# Why is "mich" in this sentence in front of the subject? "Also neulich haben mich die Eltern von meiner Freundin zum Abendessen eingeladen."

Tags: word-order

I thought "mich" should be after the subject, becasue "mich" is the accusative in this sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong, both variants are equally possible, since German is quite tolerant in respect to word order; there is just a tendency to put more emphasized words to the front of the sentence, see [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/46848/1696). So

> Die Eltern meiner Freundin haben mich neulich zum Essen eingeladen.

would emphasize *Eltern*.

(Definitely colloquial is *die Eltern von meiner Freundin* which can be shortened to the more universal *die Eltern meiner Freundin*).