# Gibt es einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung, wenn ich "früher" an anderer Stelle und nicht am Anfang eines Satzes schreibe?

Tags: difference, word-order

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46848*

Ich habe diese Beispiele:

> Früher war ich so wie du, aber jetzt bin ich anders.

und

> Ich war früher so wie du, aber jetzt bin ich anders.

Welcher Satz ist richtig? Wenn beide okay sind, was ist dann der Unterschied zwischen ihnen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beide bedeuten exakt das selbe mit leicht unterschiedlicher Betonung.

Im deutschen schreibt man die Dinge, die man besonders betonen möchte an den Anfang des Satzes, die Satzstellung ist generell sehr frei.

> **Früher** war ich so wie du

Betont das "Früher"... Man erwartet, dass ein Bezug auf die Gegenwart kommt.

> **Ich** war früher so wie du

Hier wird die Betonung auf die eigene Person gelegt. Ein weiterführender Satz, der diese Bedeutung transportiert, wäre:

> aber Deine Mutter war ganz anders

Du könntest auch schreiben:

> **So wie Du** war ich früher (auch)....

Hier liegt die Betonung auf der Gleichheit "so wie Du"...

> **War** ich früher so wie du, so bin ich doch jetzt anders

Ist ebenfalls möglich, würde aber im normalen Alltagsleben als "geschwollen", "altmodisch" oder zumindest gehobene / lyrische Sprache gelten. Hier liegt die Betonung auf der Vergangenheit "war"...

Comment: Alle Stellungen sind brauchbar und richtig, und die Hervorhebung kann auch durch die Betonung mit der Stimme gemacht werden. Es gibt auch noch einen alten Zopf, den wir in der Schule gelernt haben. Man soll die Sätze nicht immer mit "Ich " beginnen. Aber das war noch in einer Zeit vor dem hypertrophierten Ego- und Individualismu und vor dem Selfie-Zeitalter. Ja, da kannte man noch so etwas wie Demut, Bescheidenheit und sich Hinten-anstellen. ;)

Comment: Vollkommen korrekt: In der gesprochenen Sprache kann ich natürlich jeden Satzteil durch tatsächliche Betonung hervorheben. Diese Möglichkeit habe ich in der geschriebenen Sprache nicht, weshalb es schön ist, diese *weitere* Möglichkeit der Betonung mittels Satzstellung zu besitzen. Zum Thema Bescheidenheit / Hinten-anstellen: Ich wünschte ich könnte diesen Kommentar mehrfach upvoten!

Comment: Du kannst ihn gerne als Antwort formulieren. Ich vote ihn dann für dich auf!